# HTTP_POST_ARRAYS long variables not working in php5.4

Tags: php, variables, preg-match

I have some legacy code to modify in `PHP5.4`, the script was originally written in `PHP4.0`.

The problem arises when we try to login.
`HTTP_POST_VARS` is not recognized and these `post` and `get` variables need changing to `$_POST` and `$_GET` in the entire script which is worth 30-40 script files.

Could someone share any ideas on how to change all the long variables to short `$_POST` kind.

I tried to turn on `register_long_arrays` in `php.ini` file, but it is already on and not sure what else to be done.

Comment: This ought to be trivial to do: just do a search+replace in your source code using your favourite text editor or IDE. Just because there's a lot of them doesn't mean it's hard to do.

Comment: Global search and replace?  Even if you did them one file at a time, it would only take a few hours.

Comment: Having said that, if your code dates back to PHP 4.0, and you're upgrading to 5.4, the chances are that there are a whole bunch of other compatibility issues with your code. There are a number of features that have been deprecated between those versions, and some have been completely removed.

Comment: Someone should prepare days or weeks to refactor that code, not just to find/replace so be aware, better refactor it, at least of the security issues

Comment: Being newbie I am taking careful consideration in obtaining data out of production server to local machine,as the legacy application has php and html together,without any entry point. You are right there were many issues even with mysqldump to get data out. Initially schema is imported using phpMyAdmin and then selected data is imported into all the tables,which was tedious due to key constraints.

Comment: @RoyalBg I have changed HTTP_POST_VARS and other long variables with current short variables,now the error message unidentified variables is disappeared,but still could not login to the system, what refactoring should be carried on this?

Answer (score 3):

The `register_long_arrays` directive [does no longer exist](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays):

> This directive became available in PHP 5.0.0. [...] This feature has
> been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Any decent editor out there should provide a "Replace in files" menu item (which is normally under "Edit", "Search" or a similar location). With that, it should be a 2 minute task because `HTTP_POST_VARS` is a long name that won't cause much ambiguity.

You appear to be using phpDesigner. You can find [a screen-shot in their site](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner_screenshots.php) (scroll down to "Advanced search and replace").

---

**Edit:** You seem to have panic to text editors so another alternative is to create the missing variables yourself:

```
$HTTP_GET_VARS = &$_GET;
$HTTP_POST_VARS = &$_POST;
$HTTP_POST_FILES = &$_FILES;
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS = &$_SERVER;
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS = &$_SESSION;
$HTTP_ENV_VARS = &$_ENV;
$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS = &$_COOKIE;
```

You can place this code on top of your application's main settings file, which you hopefully have (otherwise, and considering that search & replace is apparently not an option, you'd need to put the stuff in a new `*.php` file and get it magically loaded with the [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) PHP directive).

Please note we're using `&` to assign references so paired variables remain in sync (that's specially important to make `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS` actually work).

Of course, `$HTTP_...` variables were not superglobals. If you don't really understand the code, you can get faced to subtle bugs.

Comment: Is phpdesigner good for this job to run a batch file on all the scripts in one go,I am not a unix or linux person. Could you advice me on how to carry on this.

Comment: @ronypal - I remember using graphical text editors with "Replace in files" feature on Windows 95. Almost 20 years later you definitively don't need to install Linux, write bash scripts or get punch cards (unless you want to) ;-) Please see my edit.

Comment: Just find and replace the variables might not work,editing config.php would be better I hope,pl.see my edit.

Comment: @ronypal - What edit? How is it possible that upgrading code to replace a feature that was removed with its modern alternative "might not work" and changing some random setting in your app will be better?

Answer (score 0):

```
`$HTTP_GET_VARS = &$_GET;
$HTTP_POST_VARS = &$_POST;
$HTTP_POST_FILES = &$_FILES;
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS = &$_SERVER;
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS = &$_SESSION;
$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS = &$_COOKIE;`
```

put them all in config(settings) file before database valid functions start and its applicable to all the scripts belonging to the folder.